# Is there any way of getting description of processes in linux?

Tags: process

In windows 7's task manager, we can get a short description of a running process:

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsMgn.png) ([Picture source](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/identify-and-get-detailed-information-about-processes-in-windows-7/))

Can we get something similar?

One way could be to create a script, which will search the man pages or in the internet for all processes. Is there any better way?

It would be better, if I can get these features in `gnome-system-monitor` or in `KSysGuard`

[A possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122984/how-to-find-out-what-a-program-does), but it seems to be cumbersome....

Comment: Hi there, the way you've phrased this is seems more like a feature request than a question. If that's the case, you might have better luck discussing it on the application's github page.

Comment: I think it is not in standards that you can provide a description to a process while creating it. Should I ask for changing GNU/linux standards? Or to add a feature to `gnome-system-monitor`? Or to create a new app to fetch description for a process? I think the best way would be to list out every processes we don't know and search each one of them.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux doesn't require processes to give a human-readable description, so there is no such thing, sorry.

Your best bet for finding out what a process does would be to simply search for it online (Google etc).

Answer (score 1):

I use Kubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.  The process monitor (accessed by Control-Esc) shows me this.  Is that what you want.  You can then sort by cpu, process etc. [image]

Some commandline alternatives like `cat /proc/{PID}/status` are listed in the answers and comments of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/831513/411468).

Comment: It is easy to get command for a certain process, but I want to get a good **"description"**. You may understand what each process does by guessing from it's command, but this is not the case for all other processes. For example I use Linux Mint, some of the processes are(from `$USER`): `(sd-pam)`, `gvfsd`, `csd-a11y-settings`, `csd-wacom`, `nm-applet`, `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`, `goa-identity-service`. I have very little idea about these processes, and I need to search `man` pages or internet for these. **My goal is to learn what each processes does in my computer**.

Comment: Now about `cat /proc/{PID}/status`. I am not interested in knowing status of a process. I want to know why is it there in the first place, in a smoother way.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does this by reading properties of the PE that was run.

This is uncommon if at all supported by ELF so no, I wouldn't expect this to be possible without an auxiliary database on Linux. A tool that determines what package the binary belongs to and shows that package's description at best (don't know of any though).